# best way to implement observer for invoiced Order in 1.7+

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, event-observer

After 2 years of experiments in Magento, This is my first attempt to create an Observer.I had written everything in place, But iam confused with the events that i should observer for!

What i need is :

```
if the purchase is invoiced after successful payment
  do something 
if the invoice is from Admin Panel
  do the same thing
```

Current event is checkout_submit_all_after
after referencing [mage 1x events](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Events+Reference): i found lot of other events that can be triggered.

with different modules like :

```
sales_order_place_after
sales_order_invoice_pay
```

Somebody please guide me in right direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the payment type, `sales_order_invoice_pay` is not guaranteed to be called, it's safer to use `sales_order_invoice_register` which is triggered during invoice creation:

See [`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::register()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L684)

So your **config.xml** should contain:

```
  <global>
    <events>
      <sales_order_invoice_register>
        <observers>
          <your_module> <!-- any unique identifier -->
            <class>your/observer</class>
            <method>yourObserverMethod</method>
          </your_module>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_invoice_register>
    </events>
  </global>
```

In your observer, you have access to the following parameters:

```
$observer->getOrder();   // the order
$observer->getInvoice(); // the invoice (not yet saved)
```

Comment: why you have call sales_order_invoice_register as safe or sales_order_invoice_pay.i guss that that reason is function pay()...Am i right ?.pay() function called depends on payment.

Comment: Right, `invoice->register()` should always be called when invoice is created, `invoice->pay()` depends on the payment method, so it might not be called.

Comment: @fschmengler thanks for the answer. will this work for paypal processing also ?

Comment: I assume that it does. Try it out.

Comment: Ya ill try ... :)

Comment: Hi @FabianSchmengler and Amit Bera if I want to write some code after invoice successfully created. then which event will be best for m2?
1) sales_order_invoice_pay
2) sales_order_invoice_register

Comment: `sales_order_invoice_register` would fire for non paid orders, right? First part of OP's requirement is "if the purchase is invoiced _after successful payment_"

Comment: @Andy usually an invoice is created on payment, and it was stated in the question as well: **purchase is invoiced after successful payment**

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Thanks for the info. New to the world of magento and trying to implement something similar. The "usually" part makes me wonder though, in what instance(s) would an invoice be created without payment?

Comment: I wrote "usually" because don't know if all payment extensions follow this standard. Also in offline payment methods like "check/money order" the shop manager creates invoices manually and might want to do that prior to actual payment.